# Why is my electron event being delayed to the render process?

Tags: express, electron, ipc, lifecycle

I'm trying to flip a toggle switch in an electron app that starts an express server, that sends a message back to the app that the server is on.

What's happening right now is, the switch is flipped, the server is turned on, but the event isn't firing back to the render process like it should.

Instead, I have to access one of my express server routes in my browser, which will then send both the log that should have come before, as well as the new one which comes with the route request.

**index.js**

```js
const {app, BrowserWindow, ipcMain} = require('electron');

ipcMain.on('log', (event, arg) => {
  mainWindow.webContents.send('log', arg)
});

ipcMain.on('web-state', (event, current) => {
  current ? Web.turnOff() : Web.turnOn()
  event.sender.send('web-state', Web.isOn() ? true : false);
});
```

**render.js**

```js
window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');
const {ipcRenderer} = require('electron');

ipcRenderer.on('log', function(event , data) {
  console.log(data);
});

$('#web-switch').on('click', function(e) {
  var Server = !document.getElementById("web-switch").checked? Web.turnOff() : Web.turnOn();
});
```

**server.js**

```js
const Express = require('express');
const Web = Express();
const Logger = require('./logger.js');
var Server;
let mainWindow;

function turnOn() {
  return Server = Web.listen(Config.web.port || 4000, function() {
    let str = 'App awakens on port ' + Config.web.port;
    Logger.log(str, t);
  });
}

module.exports = {
  turnOn: function() {
    return turnOn();
  },
  isOn: function() {
    return Server? Server.address() : false;
  }
}
```

**logger.js**

```js
const {ipcRenderer} = require('electron');

function log(data, level) {
    let str = 'something';
    ipcRenderer.send('log', str);
}

module.exports = {
    log: function(data, level) {
       log(data,level)
    }
}
```

**index.html**

```js
require('../js/render.js');
<input type="checkbox" id="web-switch" name="web-switch">
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by editing my `turnOn()` function in `server.js`

```
function turnOn() {
  Server = Web.listen(Config.web.port || 4000);
  let str = 'App awakens on port ' + Config.web.port;
  Logger.log(str, t);
  return Server;
}
```

Best answer will go to whoever can explain why there was a delay like that when I had the log call in the callback

Answer (score 0):

I Had similiar issue where first initializing events came with a delay and only after I refocused the renderer window.

Solved it using the `did-finish-load` event:

```
win.webContents.on('did-finish-load', () => {
  // make sure to initialize your events/server here
  win.webContents.send('ping', 'whoooooooh!')
})
```